# Adding a date to each sheet in an excel file in r

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr, import

I have a excel file with numbers of housing completions for each year in Britain from 1980. I am currently using this function to manually process each sheet:

```
Process <- function(file, sheet, year)  {
      read_excel(file, sheet = sheet) %>% 
      slice(-(1:5)) %>% 
      rename_with(function(x) c(paste0("Table_", seq(15)))) %>% 
      select(-c("Table_6":"Table_11")) %>% 
      mutate(Year = year) 
      }
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to put this into a loop in the form:

```
books <- c("file.xlsx")  

for (book in books) {
  sheets <- excel_sheets(book)
  for (sheet in sheets) { 
Process(book, sheet, year = count)
}
}
```

which would have a count that allows sheet one to be associated with year = 1980, sheet 2 with year = 1981 and then stack each year to make a panel dataset. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: WHat is the final outcome would look like? An excel with multiple tabs tahat have added date column or a joined data sets with date column correctly added based on data from each sheet?